# How to move files of a particular YEAR to a new dir WITH relative paths?

Tags: powershell

In `Windows 7`, I would like to use `PowerShell` to move all files in the current directory and its sub-directories, sub-sub-dirs, etc, with a certain `LastWrite YEAR`, to a new directory with their relative paths.

Can somebody write me down the necessary `PowerShell` line codes to use ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Move-Item` function to move files from one path to another

Example:

`Move-Item 'c:\YourFolder\*' 'c:\DestinationFolder'`

This will move all file in a folder to the destination folder (*).

---

To move file from a certain date you will have to pipe it into a `where-object` function:

Example:

`Get-ChildItem 'C:\folder' | where-object {$_.lastwritetime.Year -eq 2013} |

Move-Item -destination 'c:\DestinationFolder'`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176910.aspx

Comment: Do match a specific year change the where condition to something like `$_.lastwritetime.Year -eq 2008`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to keep relative path. what u need is CD to the source DIR then update

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | where {$_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq 2012}
```

and run

```
    $baselength = (Get-Location).Path.Length + 1
    $destDir = 'G:\dest'

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | where {$_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq 2012}

    $files | foreach {
        Write-Verbose "moving $_.fullname"    
        $dest = Join-Path $destDir $_.FullName.Substring($baselength)
        if ( -not (Test-Path (Split-Path $dest)))
        {
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path (Split-Path $dest) | Out-Null
        }
        Move-Item $_.FullName $dest -Force
    }
```